# SQL calculating difference between columns

Tags: mysql, sql, calculated-columns

I'm a bit of a newby at SQL and I don't really understand what to do here, so any help is really appreciated. I have a table full of readings from different readers, there's like 500.000 of them, so I can't do this by hand.

I received the table without the difference in it. I managed to calculate it, but there's a bit of a problem there...

It looks a bit like this:

```
reader_id |    date    | reading | difference
   1      | 01-01-2013 |   205   |     0
   1      | 02-01-2013 |   210   |     5
   1      | 03-01-2013 |   213   |     3
  ...     |     ...    |   ...   |    ...
   1      | 31-12-2013 |   2451  |     4
   2      | 01-01-2013 |   8543  |    6092
   2      | 02-01-2013 |   8548  |     5
```

reader_id and date form the primary key. The combination is unique.

How can I make sure I don't get the difference calculated when the last column contained a different reader_id?

When querying my data with a query like this one, the data get skewed by the incorrect difference between the two reader_ids:

```
SELECT AVG(difference), reader_id FROM table GROUP BY reader_id
```

Comment: look up LEAD or LAG window functions.  also what database? also show your existing SQL

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to see. I imported this from a SQL file into a database in phpmyadmin, it has 2 tables, one containing some info about the meters, and this one, showing the date of the reading and the actual reading. I don't have the query I used for calculation the difference anymore :( I made it on another computer. I'm really new at SQL and I don't know much more than SELECT and DELETE etc.

Comment: Your potential answers are affected by the database in use. Please tag your question with the database (sql-server, MySQL, oracle, etc.) but ideally with the version (e.g. sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, etc.)

Comment: Ah okay, I didn't know that. Using MySQL 5.6.16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For

> I just want to get the average difference for each reader.

your query is perfectly good. I think you got something wrong in your difference calculation. The first value for reader_id=2, 6092, is the difference of the last reading from reader1 and the first reading from reader 2, i don't think that makes sense. If i'm not mistaken, the difference value is the current day reading - previous day reading. Therefore you should set the difference value of the first reading of each reader to 0.

You can do this with the following query:

```
UPDATE table t INNER JOIN (SELECT reader_id, min(date) as first_day FROM table GROUP BY reader_id) as tmp ON tmp.reader_id=t.reader_id AND tmp.first_day=t.date SET t.difference=0
```

Then

```
SELECT AVG(difference), reader_id FROM table GROUP BY reader_id
```

will do what you expect.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed my problem. You just rephrased it a bit. Do you have a solution for removing the numbers that do not make sense?

Comment: You just have to find the min date for each user and update that record: 
`UPDATE table t 
 INNER JOIN (SELECT meter_id, min(date) as first_day
    FROM table
    GROUP BY meter_id) as tmp ON tmp.meter_id=t.meter_id AND tmp.first_day=t.date
SET t.difference=0`

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want the average difference, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT
    meter_id,
    MAX(reading) - MIN(reading) / COUNT(*) average_difference
FROM table
GROUP BY meter_id
ORDER BY meter_id;
```

It works on the logic that the the total difference for a given meter_id should be equal to `MAX(reading) - MIN(reading)`.